# Python merge two lists of dicts, where dict key matches

Tags: python

I have two lists containing ~100 dicts in each. A dummy illustration is shown here:

```
first = [
    {"ip-10-1-1-1": {"job": {"company": "IBM", "title": "engineer"}}},
    {"ip-10-1-1-20": {"job": {"company": "Dell", "title": "manager"}}},
    {"ip-10-1-1-35": {"job": {"company": "Apple", "title": "CEO"}}},
]

second = [
    {"ip-10-1-1-1": {"demographics": {"age": 30, "gender": "female"}}},
    {"ip-10-1-1-20": {"demographics": {"age": "30", "gender": "male"}}},
    {"ip-10-1-1-49": {"demographics": {"age": "32", "gender": "female"}}},
]
```

I'm trying to merge these with this result:

```
[
    {
        "ip-10-1-1-1": {
            "demographics": {"age": 30, "gender": "female"},
            "job": {"company": "IBM", "title": "engineer"},
        }
    },
    {
        "ip-10-1-1-20": {
            "demographics": {"age": "30", "gender": "male"},
            "job": {"company": "Dell", "title": "manager"},
        }
    },
    {"ip-10-1-1-35": {"job": {"company": "Apple", "title": "CEO"}}},
    {"ip-10-1-1-49": {"demographics": {"age": "32", "gender": "female"}}},
]
```

I can nearly accomplish this by looping over `second` and `first` like so:

```
merged = []
for d1 in second:
    for k1 in d1.keys():
        for d2 in first:
            for k2 in d2.keys():
                if k2 == k1:
                    d1[k1]["job"] = d2[k2]["job"]
    merged.append(d1)
print(merged)
```

I'm new to python however and I'm hoping/thinking there's gotta be a more pythonic way to do this.

EDIT: To further complicate things - I can have keys in `first` but not `second`, and vice versa. I've updated the example to reflect this.

Comment: Please post an updated question (with an input/output example you're interested in)

Comment: Can either list contain multiple dictionaries with the same *top-level* key? e.g. `[{'u1':,,,}, {'u2':...}, {'u1':...}]`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco isn't that what I've done above? I show the two lists and my desired results, along with an ugly solution I have but don't like...

Comment: Well, I gave you a solution for the example that you posted :) but you didn't like it because the keys you provided us are not correct. Well, then please update your example with the keys you're talking about and I'll change my answer accordingly

Comment: a very ugly looking solution and not pythonic `[{list(i[0].keys())[0]:{l:k[l] for j in i for k in j.values() for l in k}} for i in zip(first, second)]`

Comment: @wwii, it's not suitable for [codereview.se] in its current form, as _example code_ isn't suitable for review - they need real, finished code.

Comment: Can we assume the lists are in order with each other?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Apologies, I misread your first comment. I didn't realize you asked for an UPDATED version of the example. You did indeed solve the problem I posed initially. Thank you.

Comment: @TobySpeight - just had a discussion in the SO Python chat - retracted my vote..

Comment: Are you looking for pure python solutions or can you use *external* libraries/packages? Can either list contain multiple dictionaries with the same top-level key? e.g. `[{'u1':...}, {'u2':...}, {'u1':...}]`..?

Comment: @Felipe yes I can order them.

Comment: Quite a few SO Q&A's regarding merging lists of dicts - did none of them help or work for you? `python merge two lists of dicts site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
first = [
    {"user_1": {"job": {"company": "IBM", "title": "engineer"}}},
    {"user_2": {"job": {"company": "Dell", "title": "manager"}}},
    {"user_3": {"job": {"company": "Microsoft", "title": "manager"}}},
]
second = [
    {"user_2": {"demographics": {"age": "30", "gender": "male"}}},
    {"user_1": {"demographics": {"age": "30", "gender": "female"}}},
]


def merge_list_of_dicts(list_of_dicts, current={}):
    get_key = lambda d: next(iter(d))
    get_value = lambda d: next(iter(d.values()))

    for d in list_of_dicts:
        key = get_key(d)
        value = get_value(d)

        if key not in current:
            current[key] = value
        else:
            current[key].update(value)

    return current


output = merge_list_of_dicts(second, merge_list_of_dicts(first))
print(output)
```

Will take care of extra keys in `first`, as well as out of order dictionaries (notice `first` and `second` list above). Outputs:

```
{
    "user_1": {
        "job": {"company": "IBM", "title": "engineer"},
        "demographics": {"age": "30", "gender": "female"},
    },
    "user_2": {
        "job": {"company": "Dell", "title": "manager"},
        "demographics": {"age": "30", "gender": "male"},
    },
    "user_3": {"job": {"company": "Microsoft", "title": "manager"}},
}
```

If you want a cleaner API:

```py
def merge_list_of_dicts(d1: dict, d2: dict):
    def merge(list_of_dicts, current={}):
        get_key = lambda d: next(iter(d))
        get_value = lambda d: next(iter(d.values()))

        for d in list_of_dicts:
            key = get_key(d)
            value = get_value(d)

            if key not in current:
                current[key] = value
            else:
                current[key].update(value)

        return current
    return merge(d2, merge(d1))


output = merge_list_of_dicts(first, second)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible one-line solution:

```
result = {f'user_{i + 1}': dict(**d1[f'user_{i + 1}'], **d2[f'user_{i + 1}'])
          for i, (d1, d2) in enumerate(zip(first, second))}
```

If you are using python >=3.8 then you can use assignments in the dict comprehension:

```
result = {(key := f'user_{i + 1}'): dict(**d1[key], **d2[key])
          for i, (d1, d2) in enumerate(zip(first, second))}
```

Comment: I should have clarified - in reality I'll actually be dealing with UUIDs or possibly IP addresses, instead of `user_1`, `user_2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

final_list = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(
    sorted(first + second, key=lambda x: tuple(x)[0]), key=lambda x: tuple(x)[0]
):
    temp = {key: {}}
    for d in group:
        _, value = tuple(*d.items())
        temp[key].update(value)
    final_list.append(temp)
print(final_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ip-10-1-1-1': {'job': {'company': 'IBM', 'title': 'engineer'}, 'demographics': {'age': 30, 'gender': 'female'}}}, {'ip-10-1-1-20': {'job': {'company': 'Dell', 'title': 'manager'}, 'demographics': {'age': '30', 'gender': 'male'}}}, {'ip-10-1-1-35': {'job': {'company': 'Apple', 'title': 'CEO'}}}, {'ip-10-1-1-49': {'demographics': {'age': '32', 'gender': 'female'}}}]
```

Comment: Hmm I think this gets me close, thanks. I also should have clarified too that I can have keys in first but not second, and vice versa.