# Merge two multi dimention dict and only add what is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have been trying to merge these two:

```
A
{'v1': {'configuration': {'$schema': '...', 'network': {'$schema': '...'}}}}
E
{'v1': {'configuration': {'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}}}
```

The result should be:

```
{'v1': {'configuration': {'$schema': '...', 'network': {'$schema': '...', 'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}}}
```

> This is one set of data. So I have other situations where that follow `v1` is not just `configuration`. All I am trying to do is add in the **dict** the elements from another **dict** that it doesn't have. Also the *A* always has precedent.

I tried using one of the examples: [Python merge two lists of dicts, where dict key matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66602058/python-merge-two-lists-of-dicts-where-dict-key-matches)

```
    def merge_list_of_dicts(d1: dict, d2: dict):
        def merge(list_of_dicts, current={}):
            try:
                get_key = lambda d: next(iter(d))
                get_value = lambda d: next(iter(d.values()))

                for d in list_of_dicts:
                    key = get_key(d)
                    value = get_value(d)

                    if key not in current:
                        current[key] = value
                    else:
                        current[key].update(value)

                return current
            except:
                return current

        return merge(d2, merge(d1))

print(merge_list_of_dicts(A, E))
```

> I added the try/exception because without it I get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

The result is:

```
{}
```

I also tried:

```
def myseconfunc(a, b):

        print('===========')
        
        a_keys = set(a.keys())
        b_keys = set(b.keys())

        commons = a_keys.intersection(b_keys)
        #print('commons')
        #print(commons)
        for common in commons:
            if type(a) == dict:
                a = myseconfunc(a[common], b[common])
                print('common:')
                print(common)
                print('a:')
                print(a)
                print('b:')
                print(b[common])

                a.update(b[common])

        return a
```

But I get this:

```
{'$schema': '...', 'entries': {'$schema': '...'}, 'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}, 'configuration': {'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}}
```

For more details here is what the prints look like:

```
===========
common:
network
a:
{'$schema': '...'}
b:
{'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}
===========
common:
configuration
a:
{'$schema': '...', 'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}
b:
{'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}
===========
common:
v1
a:
{'$schema': '...', 'entries': {'$schema': '...'}, 'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}
b:
{'configuration': {'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}}
===========
```

I am using: Python 3.9.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive algorithm that passes your example

```
import copy

A = {'v1': {'configuration': {'$schema': '...', 'network': {'$schema': '...'}}}}
E = {'v1': {'configuration': {'network': {'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}}}

expected = {'v1': {'configuration': {'$schema': '...', 'network': {'$schema': '...', 'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}}}}

def safe_update_dict(d_to: dict, d_from: dict, inplace: bool=False):
    def fn(d_to: dict, d_from: dict):
        for k in d_from:
            if k in d_to:
                if isinstance(d_to[k], dict):
                    d_to[k] = fn(d_to[k], d_from[k])
            else:
                d_to[k] = d_from[k]
        return d_to
    if inplace:
        return fn(d_to, d_from)
    return fn(copy.deepcopy(d_to), d_from)

rtn = safe_update_dict(A, E)
print(str(expected) == str(rtn))  # True
```

Comment: the first version seemed to work... This one throws and error and returns: {'v1': {'configuration': {'network': {'$schema': '...', 'entries': {'$schema': '...'}}, '$schema': '...'}}}

Comment: @jnbdz Sorry edited the function to not do it in place by default but just edited it in SO and didnt re test it. Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! Everything works perfectly well. Appreciate the help.